# Gradle finds the Servlet library but not JSP, i.e. javax.servlet.jsp.tagext. How to import?

Tags: java, jsp, gradle

I'm trying to migrate my web-app to Gradle from Eclipse. I was getting errors about my Websockets, custom tags and jsp. Wishing I'd started with Gradle I made a MWE based on http://codetutr.com/2013/03/23/simple-gradle-web-application/

build.gradle (I commented out the third line, and another about jetty, really trying for MWE, which it *was* until I needed the jsp stuff)

```
apply plugin: 'java' 
apply plugin: 'war' 
//apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp' //I want Gradle to be IDE agnostic, if not portable.

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
//  providedCompile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
  providedCompile 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0'
  runtime 'javax.servlet:jstl:1.2'//.1
}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

  <servlet>
<display-name>HelloWorldServlet</display-name>
<servlet-name>HelloWorldServlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.codetutr.HelloWorldServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>HelloWorldServlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

HelloWorldServlet

```
package com.codetutr;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class HelloWorldServlet extends HttpServlet {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)  
    throws ServletException, IOException {
    resp.getOutputStream().write("Hello World.".getBytes());
}
}
```

That is as far as the tutorial goes so I added MyTagHandler.java

```
  package com.codetutr;

  import javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.*;
  import javax.servlet.jsp.*;
  import java.io.*;
  import java.util.Collections;
  import java.util.HashMap;
  import java.util.Map;

  public class MyTagHandler extends SimpleTagSupport {

      private static Map<String, String> tagDB = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<>());
      private static int iter_cnt = 0;

      public void doTag() throws JspException, IOException {
          tagDB.put(Integer.toString(iter_cnt), "Dumb Tag");
          JspWriter out = getJspContext().getOut();
          out.println("<h2>Progress</h2><table border=\"1\">");
          out.println("<tr><th>Id</th><th>State</th></tr>");
          for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : tagDB.entrySet()) {
          String value = entry.getValue();
          out.println("<tr><th>"+ entry.getKey() + "</th><td>"
                  + value + "</td></tr>");
          }
          out.println("</table>");
      }
  }
```

I get the following errors from `gradle.build`

```
basic-web/src/main/java/com/codetutor/MyTagHandler.java:3: error: package javax.servlet.jsp.tagext does not exist
import javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.*;

basic-web/src/main/java/com/codetutor/MyTagHandler.java:4: error: package javax.servlet.jsp does not exist
import javax.servlet.jsp.*;

basic-web/src/main/java/com/codetutor/MyTagHandler.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
public class MyTagHandler extends SimpleTagSupport {
```

and so on for errors where classes aren't imported properly.

[Standard way of adding JSLT 1.2.1 in a Maven Project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24262223/standard-way-of-adding-jslt-1-2-1-in-a-maven-project) is the closest q:a I could find.
I was, and will be using Tomcat (8.5) if it matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing this dependency

```
compile group: 'javax.servlet.jsp', name: 'javax.servlet.jsp', version: '2.0.0'
providedCompile group: 'javax.servlet.jsp', name: 'jsp-api', version: '2.0'
```

> 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0' -- Servlet API
>
> 'javax.servlet:jstl:1.2' ---     JSTL

Need to add support for the jsp pages.

Comment: In a more general sense it seems a good way to find this stuff out is asking here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370414/how-to-add-the-servlet-api-to-my-pom-xml

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution:

```
 dependencies {
        //providedCompile 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0'
        providedCompile 'org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-catalina:8.5.16'

    }
```