# Why can't my Tomcat server find the java Servlet in the html form

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

I am brand new to learning how to create java web applications using IntelliJIDEA.  I followed the instructions for my first demo project exactly.  But my server is giving a 404 Not found error with this message: The requested resource [/DEMO220912B_war_exploded/CalculatorServlet] is not available.  I have followed the instructions three times and keep getting the same error.  I am using Tomcat 8.5.70, which I already had in the XAMPP folder and have set this in the Run/Debug Configurations.  The URL in there is http://localhost:8080/DEMO220912b_war_exploded/.  I am using intelliJIDEA 2022.2.1 (Ultimate Edition) free trial version built on August 16, 2022. This is a very new version and I wonder if there's a bug in it.  Is there any way I can test this outside of intelliJIDEA to rule out problems with that software?  Or can anyone see something I am doing wrong?  I'm tearing my hair out.  The code is so simple.

Here is the Servlet code:

```
package com.example.demo220912b;

import java.io.*;

import jakarta.servlet.http.*;
import jakarta.servlet.annotation.*;

@WebServlet(name = "helloServlet", value = "/hello-servlet")
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private String message;

    public void init() {
        message = "Hello World!";
    }

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");

        // Hello
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<html><body>");
        out.println("<h1>" + message + "</h1>");
        out.println("</body></html>");
    }

    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

The CalculatorServlet

```
package com.example.demo220912b;

import jakarta.servlet.*;
import jakarta.servlet.http.*;
import jakarta.servlet.annotation.*;

import java.io.IOException;

@WebServlet(name = "CalculatorServlet", value = "/CalculatorServlet")
public class CalculatorServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        int a = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("a"));
        int b = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("b"));
        int sum = (a + b);

        response.getWriter().println("sum of " + a + " and " + b +" = " + sum);
    }
}
```

The JSP file

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>JSP - Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1><%= "Hello World!" %>
</h1>

<form action="CalculatorServlet" method="post">
    <p>
        Input number A: <input type="number" name="a" required />
    </p>
    <p>
        Input number B: <input type="number" name="b" required />
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="RUN" />
    </p>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer at [IntelliJ servlet errors, unable to open servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71180424/intellij-servlet-errors-unable-to-open-servlet)

I was using tomcat version 8.5.7.  It turns out that the latest version of intellijIDEA is creating jakarta. packages but the tomcat I had installed was looking for javax. packages.  I updated to tomcat 10 and all is now working.  Phew!!